# Content lazy loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The idea is to load content ex: `<div>` when it is near to visible display area.

For example I can do this with images:

```js
$(function() {
  $("img.lazy").lazyload({
    effect: "fadeIn",
    threshold : 200
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>
<img class="lazy" data-original="http://www.aripaev.ee/storyimage/EA/20150529/NEWS/150529839/AR/0/Ainar-Sulumets.jpg&ExactW=640&ExactH=420&Q=95" width="450" height="280" />
<img class="lazy" data-original="http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/pictures-1106-700x280.jpg" width="450" height="280" />
<img class="lazy" data-original="http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/thumb37-700x280.jpg" width="450" height="280" />
<img class="lazy" data-original="http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/160-700x280.jpg" width="450" height="280" />
<img class="lazy" data-original="http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/fun-facts-1-700x280.jpg" width="450" height="280" />
<img class="lazy" data-original="http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/pictures-1105-700x280.jpg" width="450" height="280" />
```

My question is, what is the cleanest way to do this for `<div>` and it's content?

---

### Edit:

I can write ad-hoc solutions myself, that would work, but I was hoping for existing lib.

```
        var $myElt = $('#item');
        var $window = $(window);
        var myTop = $myElt.offset().top;
        var myBot = myTop + myElt.height();
        var windowTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var windowBottom = windowTop + $window.height();

        if ((myTop > windowTop && myTop < windowBottom) 
        || (myBot > windowTop && myBot < windowBottom)) {
           //load item
```

Comment: [scrollReveal.js](http://scrollrevealjs.org/) has a `complete` callback.

Comment: @moonwave99 Indeed. Can you make a testable example, so I can accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your are using the the jQuery lazyload plugin, there is an option  available in the plugin where we can create an anchor element having a class with its href equal to the URL which will load the next content. This anchor element will be at the end of the container and when the anchor enters the viewport the ajax call for loading the next content will be fired.

I have used it in the past, but I dont remember the exact syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think, for better performance, it is better if you implement it without a third party library. A **possible** solution is, for example if you have "this.images_queue" as an array of image objects, you then:

- Bind scroll to the **window**
- You choose a scroll percent to load content when scroll percent exceeded. (The percent will seem static, but the length of the scroll bar is raising when lazy scrolling, so it will be smoothly dynamic)
- You choose a number if initially rendered images (here I chose 12)
- Choose a number of how many images to append when you scroll (here I chose 4)
- The "offset" will be 0 at the beginning, after that it will be updated on each load, the "end" also will be calculated, these two params will determine the part of the array to slice, that part will be appended to template on each load.
- For the initial load, you can call the function "loadMore" on the initialization of the page:

this is a possible example (with BackboneJS) but normally it will be suitable:

```
var self = this;
this.offset = 0;
$(window).bind('scroll', function(ev) {
self.loadMore(ev);
});
loadMore: function() {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
        d = $(document).height(),
        c = $(window).height();
    var scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 100; // The percent of the scroll
        if (this.offset < this.images_queue.length && (this.offset == 0 || scrollPercent >= 70)) { // For firefox you can find the scroll bar scrolled on reload while offset=0
        var end = 0;
        if (this.offset == 0) {
            end = Math.min(12, this.images_queue.length);
        } //the min is used in case (12) exceeds the images_queue boundary
            else {
            end = Math.min(this.offset + 4, this.images_queue.length);
        } //the min is used in case (offset + 4) exceeds the images_queue boundary
            data = this.images_queue.slice(this.offset, end)
        var some_images = "";
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var x = '<img class="lazy" data-original="' + data[i].image_url + '" width="450" height="280" />'
            some_images = some_images + x + '\n'; //normally works '\n'
        }
$(".divContainingImages").append(some_images); //Append the images from the sliced array
        this.offset = end;
    } //end if
} //end loadmore fun
```

- Attention: You **MUST** UNBIND SCROLL FROM WINDOW `$(window).unbind('scroll');` on all thy other pages (on initialize of each page or on the base page if you have).

Comment: Although interesting idea, I am not interested in image loading, but clear lazy loading pattern - ex: I have stock graph control, that creates svg's and it pulls quite a bit of data, that I could delay or not load control or it's data at all (if it does not come in visible area).

Comment: Alright, I thought you wanted to load something when new area is visible after scrolling, the above example is not only for images, you can put whatever you want on the "loadMore" function.